# Sending mail from Firebase webapp

Tags: email, firebase, nodemailer, firebase-hosting

```js
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://username@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com');
app.get('/sendMail', function(req,res){
 var mailOptions={
  to: 'receiver@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Test Mail',
  html: 'Testing the Mail'
 }
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
  if(err){
   res.end('Mail not sent');
  }
  else{
   res.end('Mail sent');
  }
 });
}).listen(9091);

console.log('This is running');
```

I am developing a firebase web app. I need to send an email via my web app. I saw some tutorials and found some code. Using the above code I am able to send emails. It runs in the port **9091**. The message will be sent when the address bar has **www.mywebsite.com/sendMail**. But when I host this page to Firebase what changes to be done in this code, whether there must be a change in the port number?.  Please help to implement this code in my web app.

Comment: It looks like your web app has been developed in NodeJS - a platform that runs javascript code on the server-side. But Firebase hosting is a static host, which means that the javascript will run on the client-side. If you want to host your app on Firebase, you can use create a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that sends the mail.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I think that you are saying that, I can only send the mail via cloud functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update 2019:** Alternatively, you can use the new [Trigger Email Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email/) (currently in beta).

---

As I mentioned on my comment, the problem is: your web app was built with NodeJS and you're trying to host it on a static host environment ([Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)). But Firebase also has [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) - a service that let's you run functions on a NodeJS environment. So you should deploy your app to that service instead.

It's really easy to [Get Started with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). And since you have already set up Firebase hosting, you can simply go to that directory and set up Cloud Functions by using this command:

```
firebase init functions
```

A new folder named "functions" will be created and an `index.js` file will be automatically added to that folder. Now that's the file where you're going to write your functions (we're actually just gonna need 1 function [triggered by HTTP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to send the email).

So in order to create this function, you would no longer need Express. you can remove that and then change a bit your index.js file to add firebase-functions, so it would become:

```
//var express = require('express'); No longer needed
//var app =  express(); No longer needed
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://username@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com');

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
    var mailOptions={
        to: 'receiver@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Test Mail',
        html: 'Testing the Mail'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
        if(err){
            res.end('Mail not sent');
        }
        else{
            res.end('Mail sent');
        }
    });
});
```

Now when you want to send a message, you can use this url: `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/sendMail`

Replace `<project-id>` with your Firebase Project ID.

Comment: How to use email content from a form?

Comment: @AjithRamesh - If the form is submitted with a POST method the data will be in `req.body`, and if it's a GET then the data will be in `req.query`