# Error: "Cannot find module" while running firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// const express=require('express');

var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://username@gmail.com:password5@smtp.gmail.com');
exports.sendMail=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
    var mailOptions={
        to: 'receiver@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Test Mail',
        html: 'Testing with Node.js'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
        if(err){
            res.send('Mail not sent');
        }
        else{
            res.send('Mail sent');
        }
    });
});
```

I am sending mail from my Firebase app. I use Firebase cloud functions for sending the mail as per the question I asked in [Sending email using Firebase web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980573/sending-mail-from-firebase-webapp). The above code is my index.js file.

And this is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

But while deploy the code I get an error. **Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?** What is this error. How to solve it?
[image: Error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing [`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) from your dependencies. Just add it...

```
npm install nodemailer --save
```

will result in (where `x.x.x` is the appropriate version)

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
  "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
  "nodemailer": "^x.x.x",
  "sendgrid": "^5.2.3"
}
```

This is most likely working for your development because you actually have `nodemailer` either installed locally or globally, but it's absent on the remote machine as the error points out

> Cannot find module 'nodemailer'

Comment: Should I insert as     "nodemailer": "^4.4.1",    or  "nodemailer": "~4.4.1",        how to find it

Comment: @Badhusha You can if you wish, however when you `npm install nodemailer --save` - the `--save` flag, npm will automatically insert the correct version for you. The version is controlled by the author, and can be found on the [package.json for that project](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/package.json#L3)

Comment: @Badhusha Did you solve this? Was my answer able to help you? Please let me know as I'd like to help you resolve this.

Comment: Yes, it was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My scenario is different its related to multiple package.json, I have two different package.json, one is global and another is for internal cloud functions. My mistake I installed the packages outside the cloud functions. The solution is, just to make sure to execute `npm i modulename` inside the correct directory.